# Hot to get google map from lat and lng?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I know with the use of gmap v3 i can give the center, and add pointer and specify contents of info box and in that manner I can get my map to be generated.

but I want to know that is it possible to directly just give lat and lng and directly get my map generated and what ever is address at that place it will directly come in info box. Is there any way to do it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are still going to have to instantiate the new map before you can define the center, info boxes and pushpins etc. However, the javascript to do this is around 10 lines, so it is not too much and you could certainly put it into a method if you were to be calling it many times. So effectively you would have a method which you provide a lon, lat to (perhaps a  on the page also to render the map under) and then you would set the map.

To center the map on a given lon, lat you can provide the map with the following option:-

```
center = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLon)
```

Comment: I searched every where and came to conclusion that that much code is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating coordinates using a file or database then use a php script to send an `Ajax` request to the following javascript file `mapData.js`. I recommend sending jSON object named `mapData` that contains coordinates `[lat, long]` as follows.

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['map']});

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $.getJSON("mapData.php", function(result)
   {
           var mapData=result;

     var dataTable1=new google.visualization.DataTable();
     dataTable1.addRows(mapData.length);

     dataTable1.addColumn('number', 'LATITUDE', 'Latitude');
     dataTable1.addColumn('number', 'LONGITUDE', 'Longitude');

      for(var i=0;i<mapData.length;i++) 
      {
        var coord=mapData[i]

        dataTable1.setValue(i, 0, parseFloat(coord[0]));
        dataTable1.setValue(i, 1, parseFloat(coord[1]));
     }

     var map=new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById("Map1"));
         map.draw(dataTable1, {showTip: true, useMapTypeControl:true, enableScrollWheel:true, zoomLevel:19});   

   });   
 });
```

In your html do the following

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="jQuery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="mapData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

<body>

    <div  id="Map1">


    </div>  
</body>
```

More info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map.html)